# C# Trim end of string by pattern

Tags: c#

I want to trim the end of a series of strings to remove a suffix which follows a pattern.

In the following examples, I want to trim the `Vx` suffix at the end.

The numerical part could be any number of digits.

Example strings

```
AbcV1
BcdV12
TuvV32
VwxV42
```

Output

```
Abc
Bcd
Tuv
Vwx
```

How could I implement such a logic in C#?
Is there a regex/pattern based way to use `.TrimEnd()`?

Comment: The regex you're looking for is `V\d+$` with multi-line mode enabled

Comment: @mpen I have the strings in an array so I can replace them one by one. So with this regex, the usage will look somehing like `Regex.Replace(input, "V\\d+$", "")`, right?

Comment: `input = input.TrimEnd('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'V');`

Comment: @Dim This doesn't seem to be restricted to numerals after a 'V', right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want any V with digits after that removed. This would do it.

```
public static void Main()
{
   string[] arr = { "AbcV1", "BcdV12", "TuvV32", "VwxV42" };
    
    foreach (string a in arr)
      Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(a, "V[0-9]+$", ""));
    
}
```

or

> "V[\d]+$"

whatever you prefer.

Comment: The square brackets around `[\d]` are unnecessary.